# Program not reading my if else if statement?

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm a beginner at Java so I'm not sure why the program isn't doing what I want it to after compiling. I've already declared the variables and it compiles. This is how the code looks:

```
  if((month == 2) && day >= 1 && day <= 28)
  {
     System.out.println(month + "/" + day + " is in the Winter season.");
  }
  else if((month == 2) && (day < 1 && day > 28))
  {
     System.out.println("Invalid day!");
  }
```

However when I run it:
enter month (1-12): 2 
enter day (1-28): 30

It ignores the last else if statement, as it is supposed to say invalid day! If I were to input:
enter month (1-12): 2
enter day (1-28): 20
2/28 is in the Winter season.

It does what I planned for it to do. I did change my code and with this it worked:

```
      if((month == 2) && day >= 1 && day <= 28)
  {
     System.out.println(month + "/" + day + " is in the Winter season.");
  }
  else if((month == 2) && !(day < 1 && day > 28))
  {
     System.out.println("Invalid day!");
  }
```

It worked. Can someone explain why the first code doesn't work but the second one does? Is my logic incorrect?

Comment: `day < 1 && day > 28)` - `day` can not both be less than one **and** greater than 28

Comment: OMG. i dont know why i didnt catch that. thank you for the quick reply.

Comment: You can use static code analysis tools like SonarLint that find such bugs.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
day < 1 && day > 28
```

to

```
day < 1 || day > 28
```

in your `else if`

Answer (score 0):

Your 1st code contains `(day < 1 && day > 28)` - which is not possible i.e. A day cannot be both less than 1 **AND** greater than 28 simultaneously

Your 2nd code contains `!(day < 1 && day > 28)` [Alternatively - `(day < 1 || day > 28)`] - which is possible & correct and means a day can either be less than 1 **OR** can be greater than 28

Hence,  your 2nd code is working.

Answer (score 0):

This condition

```
(day < 1 && day > 28)
```

returns true if `day` is less than 1 **and** the same `day` is more than 28, which is impossible. You should use **or** operator (`||`) instead. So your code would be

```
if((month == 2) && day >= 1 && day <= 28)
{
    System.out.println(month + "/" + day + " is in the Winter season.");
}
else if((month == 2) && (day < 1 || day > 28))
{
    System.out.println("Invalid day!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `else if` should look like:

```
else if((month == 2) && (day < 1 || day > 28))
```

Here's the explanation. You want to go into the `else if` block if two things are true:

- The month is February (i.e., `2`)
- The number of days in that month is "invalid", using the fact that there are (usually) `28` days in February.

When is a February day "invalid"? It can be invalid when it's *either* "less than 0" *or* "greater than 28". That is, you need the OR operation, `||`, instead of your current AND operation, `&&`.

Answer (score 0):

`(day < 1 && day > 28)` can never be true since an `int` can't be both lower than 1 and bigger than 28.

Update it to: `(day < 1 || day > 28)`

Answer (score 0):

&& operator will return true only if both Boolean operations are true.

```
(day < 1 && day > 28)
```

When day= 30, the first boolean expression, day<1 is evaluated to false. So the outcome is false even if the second expression is true.

```
!(day < 1 && day > 28)
```

Here, we take the NOT value of the combined expression. Even a one expression if false, it evaluate it to true.

Correct way is to use following format.

```
 else if((month == 2) && (day < 1 || day > 28))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 else if((month == 2) && (day < 1 && day > 28))
  {
     System.out.println("Invalid day!");
  }
```

In this code segment you can see that (day<1 && day>28) is wrong condition. As date can not satisfy both of them at same time. It should be like this.

```
else if((month == 2) && (day < 1 || day > 28))
  {
     System.out.println("Invalid day!");
  }
```